# How to display colliders in a apk build?

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, collider

I want to display the colliders in my game like the editor mode in a APK build, so that I can easily observe how those colliders work. Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: are those 2D or 3D colliders?

Comment: those are 3d colliders

Answer (score 0):

The green Collider-Meshes are so-called Gizmos. They are an Editor-only feature. (The axies for moving an object are for example also Gizmos.)

If you want to show them in your build, you would have to recreate them yourself, or you might find something on the Unity Asset Store.

You best bet might be to just add a Mesh Gameobject to the object if you want to visualise it in your build quickly. It would also be useful to know what you want to test on the phone and not in the Editor. There are some nice tools which allows you to test most things in the Editor, like Unity Remote for example.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best approach but you can draw meshes into your scene using [`Graphics.DrawMesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawMesh.html) like e.g.

```csharp
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class DebugColliders : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Mesh m_SphereMesh;
    private Mesh m_CapsuleMesh;
    private Mesh m_CubeMesh;

    [SerializeField]
    private Material m_ColliderMaterial;

    // little hack to get the default shape meshes
    // note that the normal collider Gizmos use actually more simple drawings but -as this is just for debugging this should be enough 
    private void Awake()
    {
        var cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        m_CubeMesh = cube.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        
        var sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        m_SphereMesh = sphere.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        
        var capsule = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Capsule);
        m_CapsuleMesh = capsule.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;

        if (Application.isPlaying)
        {
            Destroy(sphere);
            Destroy(cube);
            Destroy(capsule);
        }
        else
        {
            DestroyImmediate(sphere);
            DestroyImmediate(cube);
            DestroyImmediate(capsule);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // find all active colliders in scene
        var colliders = FindObjectsOfType<Collider>();

        // then draw their meshes
        foreach (var collider in colliders)
        {
            Mesh mesh;
            var colliderTransform = collider.transform;
            var matrix = colliderTransform.localToWorldMatrix;
            
            switch (collider)
            {
                case BoxCollider boxCollider:
                { 
                    // for a box we take the cube mesh and additionally translate and scale it according to the settings
                    mesh = m_CubeMesh;
                    matrix  *= Matrix4x4.TRS(boxCollider.center, Quaternion.identity, boxCollider.size);
                    break;
                }

                case SphereCollider sphereCollider:
                {
                    // sphere is almot the same but uses the maximum of the scales as radius 
                    // then we add center and radius settings
                    mesh = m_SphereMesh;
                    var lossyScale = colliderTransform.lossyScale;
                    matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(colliderTransform.position, colliderTransform.rotation, Vector3.one * Mathf.Max(lossyScale.x, lossyScale.y, lossyScale.z)) * Matrix4x4.TRS(sphereCollider.center, Quaternion.identity, 2 * sphereCollider.radius * Vector3.one);
                    break;
                }

                case MeshCollider meshCollider:
                {
                    // mesh is trivial
                    mesh = meshCollider.sharedMesh;
                    break;
                }

                case CapsuleCollider capsuleCollider:
                {
                    // capsule is a bit complex as they actually use a sphere, cylinder combo but this comes close enough
                    // might need some more work though
                    mesh = m_CapsuleMesh;
                    var radius = capsuleCollider.radius * 2;
                    var height = capsuleCollider.height > radius ? capsuleCollider.height : radius;
                    height *= 0.5f;
                    var size = new Vector3(radius, height, radius);
                    var rotation = capsuleCollider.direction switch
                    {
                        0 => Quaternion.Euler(0,0,90),
                        1 => Quaternion.identity,
                        2 => Quaternion.Euler(90,0,0)
                    };
                    matrix *= Matrix4x4.TRS(capsuleCollider.center, rotation, size);
                    break;
                }

                default:
                    continue;
            }

            Graphics.DrawMesh(mesh, matrix, m_ColliderMaterial, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

and as a material use some wire-frame material like e.g. the ones from [here](https://github.com/Chaser324/unity-wireframe/tree/master)